# Emploi figuratif de « rapport »

Tags: usage, étymologie, figure-de-style

J'ai lu quelque part le dialogue :

> "I'm hungry. - Do you need a screwdriver? - What? No. It doesn't make
>   any sense."

accompagné de la traduction :

> "J'ai faim. - Besoin d'un tournevis ? - Quoi ? Ça n'a pas
>   rapport !"

Cet emploi figuratif du mot *rapport* est-il courant/répandu ? D'où cet emploi vient-il ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cette expression est effectivement courante, avec de nombreuses variantes: *ça n'a pas de rapport, ça n'a aucun rapport, je ne vois pas le rapport*, etc.

Il faut comprendre ici le nom *rapport* dans le sens de "relation, lien logique" entre deux éléments, par exemple comme dans:

> Il y a un rapport entre la production de gaz à effet de serre et le réchauffement climatique.

On peut aussi utiliser *rapport* pour désigner les liens sociaux entre des personnes:

> Je n'ai plus de rapports avec ma famille depuis longtemps.